# Where to place css folder for joomla component

Tags: css, joomla

I world like to know where can I place my css folder for my joomla components. 
I have my commponent directory structure like this.

```
com_component/
    site/
        views/
        models/
        controllers/
```

should I add a css folder under site/ or site/views/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you will see one of the following:

Add an `assets` folder within site and then put any component asset in folders within that (`js`, `css`, `images`, etc). Be sure to include this folder in your base xml file if using the installer.

The more common method presently is to create a media folder and reference that. So in your install file, create a sibling folder to `site` called media. In that add a `css` folder and put css files in there. In your install file, you would add the following set to make sure that the files get installed. Final destination will be `SITE_ROOT/media/com_name/css/css_file.css`:

```
<media folder="media" destination="com_name">
    <folder>css</folder>
</media>
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, it would be under site/. But, you may also consider adding it to /media/com_component. Take a look at http://www.babdev.com/blog/139-use-the-media-folder-allow-overridable-media

Answer (score 1):

You could also put it into the views for the component, and that way users can create a Template Output Override for the component in their own templates so that updating the component does not update their changes.

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

@betweenbrain I'm not sure which is the "best practice" - creating the view in the component so the template override can be created, or creating it in the media folder?

Comment: Since the question is specifically about the CSS files not the view, I'm not sure that this works. I don't think that you can override CSS files even if in the view section.